# screen utility (terminal app) installed on my mac and I don't know where it came from. How to uninstall it?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, big-sur

I have homebrew installed on MacOS Big sur. However, when I type `brew search screen`, homebrew clearly shows that the [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) terminal app is NOT installed on my Mac through homebrew. However, in MacOS terminal, when I type `screen` or `screen --help`, the [screen utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) opens up in my terminal. I don't remember installing the [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) utility and when I look at the [screen website](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), there appear to be no binary's for MacOS, so I don't even know how this could have been installed without homebrew. Does [Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) come preinstalled as a part of MacOS? If not, how did it get installed on my mac, and most importantly, how can I uninstall it? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

When I type `which screen` into the terminal (I'm running Mac 10.14.6), I get `/usr/bin/screen` which strongly suggests this is standard with the Mac. I also see screen installed in the same place on machines running 10.6.8 and 10.5.8. Looking on Google, it seems this utility is pretty standard with Linux and BSD.

Maybe run the same command on your system, just to verify that the application lives in `/usr/bin`.

On Big Sur, the part of the file system where screen normally lives is read only. So unless you have turned that protection off, nothing could be installed there and you would be unable to remove it.

My advice would be to just ignore it, unless you found it installed somewhere else in the file system.

Comment: Screen is in fact included with macOS. You can find it both on [opensurce.apple.com/released](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/) and on Apple’s [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/screen/tree/screen-29).

Comment: Thank you, I thought there was probably a list somewhere, but couldn't remember where to look.